# json_decode own class - Warning: Depth must be greater than zero

Tags: php, json

Because I prefer a more object oriented approach I wrote my own json class to handle also json_last_error for decode and encode.

Somehow I get a php warning for the depth property of the json_decode method.

The PHP core api (eclipse PDT) for the json_decode method looks like the following:

```
function json_decode ($json, $assoc = null, $depth = null) {}
```

So far so good but if I write my own class like this:

```
function my_json_decode ($json, $assoc = null, $depth = null) {
    return json_decode($json, $assoc, $depth);
}
```

and try to run it as follow:

```
$json = '{ "sample" : "json" }';
var_dump( my_json_decode($json) );
```

I get the following warning:

```
Warning: json_decode(): Depth must be greater than zero in /
```

Did I miss anything? I thought if I pass null for a property to a method which set the property itself to null it should be fine?!

Using: Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) PHP/5.3.10

Thanks for the help!

---

[Edit] to clarify where my leak of understanding was:

I am using Eclipse Indigo + PDT. The PDT PHP core api of org.eclipse.php.core.language is different from what php.net say about json_decode:

json_decode org.eclipse.php.core.language:

```
json_decode ($json, $assoc = null, $depth = null)
```

json_decode php.net:

```
json_decode ( string $json [, bool $assoc = false [, int $depth = 512 [, int $options = 0 ]]] )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depth is the recursion depth (should be an INTEGER) of json_decode. See the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) for more details.

What you are doing is that you are setting $depth to 0. Since your json object's depth is 2. the minimum value of $depth must be `2`. Also your code would work fine with any value of depth>2, but I would recommend to use the default value of 512 (it was 128 initially which was later increased to 512 in PHP 5.3.0)

Also do note that `assoc` has to be a `bool` value.

Comment: Thanks Gopi for explaining why my object depth is 2 and why I can't pass NULL like in the PHP core api. The assoc NULL is also out of the core api. This PHP core api out of eclipse PDT confused me because it is also different from what php.net say about json_decode

Comment: @Talisin be sure to accept the answer & close the question if any answer satisfies you

Comment: I will as usual just let me find out why the eclipse PHP core api is different from php.net.

Comment: how can we say that the object's depth is 2 ?

Answer (score 2):

Depth suppose to be a number and `(int)null == 0` therefore you are passing 0 for $depth. From the php manual 512 is the default value for $depth http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Ok make sense but why does the PHP core api set it to NULL and not to $depth = 512?

Comment: Instead of telling him the default value, you should have explained what `depth` means, though I am not the downvoter.

Comment: @Talisin depth is the recursive depth which php should explore in your json object. In your case 2 & greater would work fine. I had mentioned these points in my answer

Answer (score 1):

Imho, object oriented approach doesn't worth invention of bycicle in such sort of situations. E.g. just take source code from Yii framework's [CJSON::decode method](http://code.google.com/p/yii/source/browse/tags/1.1.10/framework/web/helpers/CJSON.php#324) (or that's beter take the whole class which is quite excellent).

```
json_decode ( string $json [, bool $assoc = false [, int $depth = 512 [, int $options = 0 ]]] )
```

You can't pass NULL as depth. So your alias for json_decode() is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks, I don't need a solution which work, I need to understand why the API core set NULL but if I set it to NULL I get a warning. The CJSON::decode method of the Yii framework ignore the depth as well, right?

Comment: Look at the documentation:
`json_decode (string $json [, bool $assoc = false [, int $depth = 512 [, int $options = 0 ]]])`
You can't pass NULL as deth. CJSON::decode method ignores depth, yes, but if you aren't going to use the whole framework, just add an argument in its code in your copy.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the php.net doc. In the end it helps me to find out that my eclipse PDT core API is different of the php.net doc.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a matter of your function and the argument being set to null if it isn't passed in. The issue is because you are passing null to json_decode for the depth. Just check whether `$assoc` and `$depth` are not null and if they are not null pass them into json_decode appropriately. Also, you should make clear that `$assoc` is a bool and use a default value as such.

```
function my_json_decode ($json, $assoc = false, $depth = null) {
    if ($assoc && !$depth)
        return json_decode($json, $assoc);
    else if ($depth)
        return json_decode($json, $assoc, $depth);
    return json_decode($json);
}
```

However, I'm not sure why you would need to do this since the php-json library takes care of this for you.

Comment: Thanks for posting a solution. The reason for writing an own json class is to include the json_last_error() method into the json_decode and json_encode method and throw a possible json_error.